# Logging Issues with Fluentd in Windows Docker Environment: Error during Startup and Failure to Forward Logs

Tags: fluentd

When running the project in macOS using Docker with Fluentd for logging, there are no issues. However, when running the same project in Windows, Fluentd encounters several errors during the startup of the container, resulting in no logs being forwarded.

Errors logs

```
fluentd           | 2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 fluent/log.rb:402:error: failed to purge buffer chunk chunk_id="5fec8dc19520e0488b378ed1aa9dcf26" error_class=Errno::ENOENT error=#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ apply2files - /fluentd/log/nginx/buffers/buffer.q5fec8dc19520e0488b378ed1aa9dcf26.log.meta>
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer/file_chunk.rb:161:in `unlink'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer/file_chunk.rb:161:in `purge'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:601:in `block in purge_chunk'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:592:in `purge_chunk'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1110:in `commit_write'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1229:in `try_flush'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1538:in `flush_thread_run'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:510:in `block (2 levels) in start'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/thread.rb:78:in `block in thread_create'
fluentd           | 2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 fluent/log.rb:402:error: failed to purge buffer chunk chunk_id="5fec8dc200df70d262d50e3912a1d713" error_class=Errno::ENOENT error=#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ apply2files - /fluentd/log/frontend/buffers/buffer.q5fec8dc200df70d262d50e3912a1d713.log.meta>
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer/file_chunk.rb:161:in `unlink'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer/file_chunk.rb:161:in `purge'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:601:in `block in purge_chunk'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:592:in `purge_chunk'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1110:in `commit_write'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1229:in `try_flush'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1538:in `flush_thread_run'
fluentd           |   2023-06-23 23:02:06 +0000 [error]: #0 3.1.0/monitor.rb:202:mon_synchronize: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:510:in `block (2 levels) in start'
```

I tried different fluentd images but same issue. below is the docker compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db_test
    container_name: api
    volumes:
      - ./files:/files:rw
      - ./src:/app:rw
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: .env
    command: >
      bash -c "wait_for db:5432 db_test:5432 && sleep 30 && entrypoint.sh"
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        fluentd-async-connect: "true"
        fluentd-retry-wait: 1s
        fluentd-max-retries: 200
        tag: api.api

  fluentd:
    container_name: fluentd
    image: fluentd:v1.16-1
    ports:
      - 24224:24224
      - 24224:24224/udp
    volumes:
      - ./fluent.conf:/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf:ro
      - ./src/logs:/fluentd/log:rw
    command: >
      /usr/bin/fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf -v
    networks:
      - default
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        fluentd-async-connect: "true"
        fluentd-retry-wait: 1s
        fluentd-max-retries: 200
        tag: api.fluentd
```

fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  port  24224
</source>

<label @mainstream>
  <match api.api>
    @type file
    path         /fluentd/log/api/api
    time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d
    time_slice_wait   1m
    time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    buffer_chunk_limit 10K
    buffer_path /fluentd/log/api/buffers
    append true
    <buffer>
      path /fluentd/log/api/buffers
      chunk_limit_size 30K
      flush_mode interval
      flush_interval 5s
      flush_thread_count 2

    </buffer>
  </match>

  <match api.fluentd>
    @type file
    path         /fluentd/log/fluentd/api-fluentd
    time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d
    time_slice_wait   1m
    time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    buffer_chunk_limit 10K
    buffer_path /fluentd/log/fluentd/buffers
    append true
    <buffer>
      path /fluentd/log/fluentd/buffers
      chunk_limit_size 30K
      flush_mode interval
      flush_interval 5s
      flush_thread_count 2

    </buffer>
  </match>
  
</label>
```

Comment: `failed to purge buffer chunk chunk_id="5fec8dc200df70d262d50e3912a1d713" error_class=Errno::ENOENT error=#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ apply2files - /fluentd/log/frontend/buffers`. Seems to me the issues is permissions. Either it can't create the buffer or it has but it doesn't have the required permissions.

Comment: Isn’t the volume in docker compose should give it permission

Comment: why do you have two paths for buffer? One in buffer directive and one outside? Also your config says `/fluentd/log/api/buffers` and `/fluentd/log/fluentd/buffers` while your logs point to `frontend` and `nginx`?

Comment: The first buffer path is creating the dir and second is for flushing the logs. With regard to the logs,I just took the example of frontend and nginx. The error logs is all same for all containers